# XML error on Chrome but is fine on FF?

Tags: javascript, php, xml, google-chrome, backbone.js

I'm using PHP to retrieve data and publish the data as an RSS feed.  The script I have works fine on Firefox but not on Chrome.

This works on Firefox but not chrome:

```
getData.php?id=1744225&odds=1
```

This works on Chrome:

```
getData.php?id=1744225&amp;odds=1
```

Chrome seems to need the full ampersand code in the URL:

```
"&amp;"
```

The full URL is rendered in a backbone template like so:

```
<a href="/php/getData.php?id=<%= model.id %>&amp;odds=1" target="_blank"><i class="icon-rss" id="rss"></i></a>
```

On Chrome this is the error I'm getting:

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 1066: EntityRef: expecting ';'    
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

How can I prevent this error being produced on Chrome?  It looks like the template has the correct code in it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem once - I was lazy and set up a javascript event listener that replaced the '&'s with &

Comment: replaced the '&'s with the html character